# Azure JavaScript TTS-SDK for getting result as an in-memory stream ERROR

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

audioData: undefined,
errorDetails: "Unable to contact server. StatusCode: 500,
ErrorDetails: "Unable to contact server. StatusCode: 500, undefin…**external_ocsp_ocsp**.Agent is not a constructor",

```
//code
synthesizeSpeech() {
      let that = this;
      const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
        "********",
        "********"
      );
      speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "zh-CN";
      const synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);
      var soundContext = undefined;
      try {
        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext ||window.webkitAudioContext || false;
        if(AudioContext){
          soundContext = new AudioContext();
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
        "你好你好你好你好你好你好你好.",
        result => {
          console.log(result)
          if(result.audioData && soundContext){
            var source = soundContext.createBufferSource();
            soundContext.decodeAudioData(result.audioData,function(newBuffer){
              source.buffer = newBuffer;
              source.connect(soundContext.destination);
              source.start(0);
            })
          }
          synthesizer.close();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          synthesizer.close();
        }
      );
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in [Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js) v1.12, which will be released recently. You can download the compiled js file after the release or you can compile it from the master of the [sdk repo](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js).